# What's known about recurrences involving $(a_n)^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I've run across the recurrence $a_{n+1} = (a_n)^2 + 1$ in the past.  Unfortunately, the referrence escapes me.  However, my impression was that recurrences involving the product of previous terms (such as $a_{n+1} = (a_n)(a_{n-1})$) are difficult to solve.  I'm wondering what is known for this very general problem.

(1)  Is there a known way to solve recurrences involving the product of previous terms?  Or, what is known about these?

(2)  What are these recurrences called?  Do they have a general name (such as non-linear recurrences)?

(3)  Where can I find more literature on the subject?

(4)  Who are some experts that have dealt with this?

Comment: So, [quadratic maps](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html)?

Comment: In general though, even simple recurrences like the [logistic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) possess no closed-form solutions.

Comment: [...and if you have a general complex number instead of 1 in the first recurrence you gave...](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html)

Comment: @J.M.:  Yes, Quadratic maps!  I've been rewriting $a_{n+1}$ as $a_{n^2}$.  I guess this is far from novel, though.

Comment: After answering [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/781024), I was searching to find similar questions. I came across your question and thought that perhaps that question was what you were remembering.

Comment: @robjohn:  I'm not totally sure, but that question looks interesting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$a_{n+1} = a_n a_{n-1}$ happens to be quite easy to solve: if $b_n = \log a_n$ then $b_n$ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence.

The only recurrences of the form $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + c$ that have anything like a closed form solution occur when $c = 0$ (obvious) and when $c = -2$ (where the solution is given by $a_n = 2 \cos 2^n \theta$ where $\theta$ is determined by $a_0$).  For all other values of $c$ you get very complicated behavior, and the situation for more general nonlinear recurrences is even worse.  People study questions like these in [dynamical systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) and related areas; one keyword you might use to start your exploration is [Julia set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set).

Like many other classes of sufficiently general problems in mathematics, the problem is hopelessly complicated in general and people study interesting special cases.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime ago I considered the sequence of fractions defined by $a_1 = 1/2$, $a_{n+1} = (a_n^2 + 1)/2$, in some probabilistic context; see [OEIS seqence A167424](http://oeis.org/A167424) . This sequence is closely related to the one defined by $a_1 = 1/2$, $a_{n+1}=a_n-a_n^2$, see [OEIS sequence A076628](http://oeis.org/A076628), whose asymptotics as $n \to \infty$ was analyzed [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/somos).

Answer (score 2):

If we have a sequence $a_{n+1} = f(a_n, ..., a_{n-k})$ where $f$ is a quadratic polynomial in $k$ variables, then we can use this recurrence relation to write down a "simplified" recurrence relation:

$a_{n+1} = g(a_{n-k})$ where $g$ is a polynomial of even degree.

Define a new sequence $b_j = a_{(k+1) \cdot j}$.

Then $b_{j+1} = a_{kj + k + j + 1} = g(a_{(k+1)j}) = g(b_j)$.

Notice that if $a_n$ converges, then so does $b_n$ and $\lim a_n = \lim b_n$. Denote $\lim b_n$ by $b$.

As $g$ is continuous,

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(b_{n+1}) = g( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n )$

Thus, $g(b) = b$, so the limit of the sequence $a_n$ must be one of the fixed points of $g$.

To find the fixed points of $g(x)$, one must find the roots of the polynomial $g(x) - x$ (of which there are only finitely many), and to solve this problem one can use a variety of methods, like for example Newton's method.

Comment: [There is still room for crazy behavior, though.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/LogisticEquationBifurcation_850.gif)

Comment: Yep, whenever you are iterating a map you are likely to find crazy behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Kelley and Peterson's textbook [1]. The problem you are looking at here is a recurrence relation as you have stated. You also hear them called difference equations. If you are familiar with differential equations, these difference equations are the discrete analog of differential equations [2].

Kelley and Peterson go very in depth with solving different types of difference equations. They give a nice overview of several different methods.

I hope this helps you! If you have any other questions, feel free to email me or contact me through my blog http://www.tylerclark12.com/blog.

[1] Kelley, W. & Peterson, A. (2001). Difference Equations: An Introduction with Applications (2nd Ed.). San Diego, CA: Academic Press.

[2] Weisstein, Eric W. "Recurrence Equation." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecurrenceEquation.html